# How to store multiple data of the same kind in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, badge

I was trying to make a **Learning to-do list** for PHP.
I used bootstrap classes: collapse and list-group. 
Each list tag has 2 badges which serve for counters.

Badge 1 = no of time I learnt or revise the chapter.

Badge 2 = no of time I actually used the concept from the chapter.

When I click on the badges, the number on them should increase by one.
I will add options for adding new chapters and sub chapters later.

For now, I want to save the values of the badges on my local storage for later use.

When I refresh the page, all the badges should be updated with their current values.

I already know how to get and retrieve data from local storage, but I do not know how to implement it in the current situation.

```js
var badges= document.querySelectorAll('.badge');
badges.forEach(function (e) {
 e.addEventListener('click', incrementBadge);
});

function incrementBadge(e){
  let num =Number(e.target.textContent)+1;
  e.target.textContent=num;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#php">Php</button>
 <div class="collapse" id="php">
  <ul class="list-group  mt-0">
   <li class="list-group-item">Iteration
    <span data-type="revise"class="badge badge-info float-right">4</span>
    <span data-type="practice" class="badge badge-success float-right mr-3">2</span>
   </li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Selection
    <span data-type="revise" class="badge badge-info float-right">0</span>
    <span data-type="practice" class="badge badge-success float-right mr-3">2</span>
   </li> 
  </ul>      
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's not difficult to do.  Have you tried writing the code yourself?  Here's [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).  Your strategy will be to set up the following logic: 1) assign the badge values from local storage on page load for any values that are set in local storage, and 2) write to local storage in your click event to update the value for the clicked badge.  The hardest thing to do will probably be deciding how to uniquely identify the badges when you store them.

Comment: I already know how to store and retrieve data from local storage. My problem is that I do not know how to uniquely identify the badges for storing and retrieving their values later and implement that in the javascript code.

Comment: If you run your snippet now, what identifies your two rows?  It's the labels of `Iteration` and `Selection`, right?  Unless you associate those rows with a numeric ID, that's your unique identifier right there.  The next question is how you get that text-based identifier from the markup into your javascript.  Do you have any ideas on how that might be accomplished?  If it were me, I'd start by adding those strings as an attribute somewhere in the markup. Where do you think that might best go?

Comment: I initially tried using the chapter title and the current list data for the key of the data to be stored and I got the value of the badge being clicked with some regexp. Thanks Joseph, I think I got an idea. I will use an array with name of the chapter(ie php) and the rows numeric ID will be used as index for the array. but I still cannot think of how to identify which badges and their values and store them in key-value pair and retrieve them later

Comment: Excellent.  How to identify the badge.  You already know which one was clicked by accessing `e.target`.  From that you are already accessing the value using `.textContent`, which works. You can use `e.target.getAttribute('your-attribute-name')`.  With that, you could place your key for that value on the badge itself with `<span class="badge badge-info float-right" your-attribute-name="whatever">`.  You could also access a parent attribute with `e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('whatever')`.  That choice is up to you.  Could you please update your question with similar logic?

Comment: I just added ids for the badges(practice and revise) From there, How do I proceed to get their individual values. key= php[Row index], value=??

Comment: `id` is an attribute you can use, but you have to be careful with it.  They must be unique for your HTML to be valid.  Currently your `id`s are not unique.  Also, the value you've assigned to them is not so much a unique identifier as category.  I would suggest changing them from `id="revise"` and `id="practice"` to `data-type="revise"` and `data-type="practice"` respectively.  the `data-` convention is not required but it's more semantically correct to prefix your custom attributes with `data-`.

Comment: I got your point , and from there, how do I proceed in js to store the values of the badges. Any suggestions. I just can't think right lol.

Comment: So now you can the type of badge, but you still don't have the row. You can use the same process to identify rows (e.g. `<li class="list-group-item" data-id="selection">`).  From your javascript you access those values using `getAttribute`.  Inside your click attribute you can build up the unique identifier (row+type) by accessing `e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id')` and `e.target.getAttribute('data-type')`.  From there you can concatenate them to for a unique string (e.g. "iteration.practice") or add them to a javascript object (e.g. `[{id:"iteration",type:"practice"}]`).

Comment: So using the example above, a unique string can be build using `let key = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + '.' + e.target.getAttribute('data-type')`.   That will be you key you use in your local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The code now can store with key-value pair, but another problem is how to retrieve the values from the LS and display them back to the badges to their respective rows.

Comment: Correct.  What format did you choose for the local storage key?

Comment: key = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + '.' + e.target.getAttribute('data-type'); e.g iteration.practice = 3;

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've established a codebase that stores the data, your problem of getting the data becomes trivial.  You already iterate over badges, so in that same step, you can easily set the value based on the local storage.  If the key doesn't exist in local storage, `.getItem` will return `null`.  This allows you to set a default value using a logical OR operator.  Your "getting" code can be as follows:

```
let key = e.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + '.' + e.getAttribute('data-type');
e.textContent = localStorage.getItem(key) || 0;
```

StackOverflow sandboxes the snippet editor, so the local storage code in the following snippet is commented out.  You can, however, see it in action [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/yn9c9kk4/).

There are other approaches you can take to store these values.  This is just a rudamentary approach, but hopefully this helps you on your way to makeing a fully fleshed out application.

```js
var badges= document.querySelectorAll('.badge');
badges.forEach(function (e) {
  let key = e.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + '.' + e.getAttribute('data-type');
 //e.textContent = localStorage.getItem(key) || 0;
 e.addEventListener('click', incrementBadge);
});

function incrementBadge(e){
  let num =Number(e.target.textContent)+1;
  let key = e.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + '.' + e.target.getAttribute('data-type');
  //localStorage.setItem(key, num);
  e.target.textContent=num;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-5">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 <button class="btn btn-block btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#php">Php</button>
 <div class="collapse" id="php">
  <ul class="list-group  mt-0">
   <li class="list-group-item" data-id="iteration">Iteration
    <span data-type="revise"class="badge badge-info float-right">4</span>
    <span data-type="practice" class="badge badge-success float-right mr-3">2</span>
   </li>
   <li class="list-group-item" data-id="selection">Selection
    <span data-type="revise" class="badge badge-info float-right">0</span>
    <span data-type="practice" class="badge badge-success float-right mr-3">2</span>
   </li> 
  </ul>      
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your immense help. I understood your code very well. I am currently making another version of the code with new features, like adding a new collapse element and row contents from javascript. I will keep you informed.

Comment: @TechXpert Cool! Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Hey Joseph, I just completed the final version of the project and I want your review on it: https://jsfiddle.net/yuvraj034c/pznjpb2c/   However, the  local storage and and badges are not incrementing on Js fiddle. It is working fine in my text editor: There are some notes you need to remember: First, when adding subchapters, write id of the chapter followed by * followed by subchapter name. For e.g if you want to add loops to php, write php*loops in the input box for subchapters. To delete a subchapter: write php.loops ( not *) in the delete input box.

Comment: If you want to delete a chapter, type chapter in the delete box and press del button . Then open console and copy the provided code and change value of here to name of the chapter to be deleted(php in this case) and reload the page.

Comment: I want to thank you again for helping me out on the logic and code for local storage. I would never have thought like that. This is 2nd or 3rd working program I built for personal use. I am still learning web developement. I know html/css/bootstrap/javascript upto ajax(currently learning), basic php and thats it. Can you give me some advice for what and how to learn effectively and fast.